# Pointer Passing and Parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, return-value

I am having a problem in my code right now. I can't seem to get what I need and return the address of my structure "b" so other functions can use it. If you can help me out that would be great!

Here is my necessary code:

```
    int notFound = 0;
int choiceNumber;
int arraySize;
Basketball * b;



b = readFile(arraySize, notFound, &b);
```

Here is the function that I am having the problems:

```
Basketball * readFile(int & arraySize, int & notFound, Basketball * &b)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("games.txt");
if(inputFile.fail())
{
    cout << "The file name \"games.txt\" was not found!" << endl;
    notFound = 1;
}
else
{
    inputFile >> arraySize;

    b = new Basketball [arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> b[i].visitTeam >> b[i].homeScore >> b[i].visitScore;
    }

    return & b;
}

}
```

My build errors are these:

```
Error: invalid intialization of non-const reference of type basketball*& from an rvalue of type Basketball**
Error: In passing arguement 3 of Basketball* readfile(int&,int&, Basketball*&)
Error: Cannot convert Basketball** to Basketball* in return
```

If you can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: You don't need the & in "return & b;" this just creates a pointer to your pointer. Try just "return b;"

Comment: @jamolnng That fixed the third error. What is going on with the first two?

Comment: Well in the first one you are creating a pointer to a pointer again, so this readFile(arraySize, notFound, &b); you should remove the & before the b.

Comment: Make your title describe the question, please, rather than just listing two broad topics of programming.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `b` already is a pointer, using `&b` will create a pointer to the pointer. Drop the address-of operator `&`.

The error message is *very* clear about it, same with you returning a pointer to a pointer when you declared is a returning only a single pointer.

Answer (score 1):

"return b;" is what yoy want, not "return &b"

&b Is the address of Basketball*, so you would end with incorrect Basketbal**

Answer (score 1):

As others already wrote, since `b` is already a pointer, `return b;` will fix your error.

If you do `return &b;` you are returning the *address* of a pointer, i.e. a *"double level indirection"* pointer, which would be a `Basketball**`.

However, let me add that you may simplify your C++ code using more modern idioms, like using `std::vector<Basketball>` instead of raw pointers and raw arrays, e.g.:

```
std::vector<Basketball> readFile(int & notFound);
```

Note that a `vector` knows its own size (e.g. you can call its `size()` method to query for it), so you don't need a separate reference parameter to store the size.

And, moreover, a `vector` *automatically* cleans up its content, thanks to its destructor. So, you don't put a burden on the caller to make an explicit call to `delete[]` to release the allocated array.

As an alternative, you could use a `bool` parameter meaning "not found", and pass the vector as non-const reference, e.g.:

```
// Returns false if not found, true if found
bool readFile(std::vector<Basketball>& v);
```

Or, depending on your design, you may even return a `std::vector`, and throw an exception in the not-found case.